# FullCalendar dayGridMonth ssort events based on resource priority rather than the time axis

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to sort events based on resource priority rather than the time axis.

These are my eventsL

```
title: 'Event 1', start: '2024-02-01 09:00:00', resourceId: 'resource1' ,
title: 'Event 2', start: '2024-02-01 10:00:00', resourceId: 'resource1' ,  
title: 'Event 3', start: '2024-02-01 11:00:00', resourceId: 'resource2' ,  
title: 'Event 4', start: '2024-02-01 12:00:00', resourceId: 'resource2' ,  
title: 'Event 5', start: '2024-02-01 13:00:00', resourceId: 'resource1' ,  
title: 'Event 6', start: '2024-02-01 14:00:00', resourceId: 'resource1' ,
```

This data is displayed like this:

```
2024-02-01  
Event 1 id:1  
Event 2 id:1  
Event 3 id:2  
Event 4 id:2  
Event 5 id:1  
Event 6 id:1
```

But I want to sort them by resourceID like this:

```
2024-02-01  
Event 1 id:1  
Event 2 id:1  
Event 5 id:1  
Event 6 id:1  
Event 3 id:2  
Event 4 id:2
```

How can I realize it?

I read fullCalendar documents, but I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried anything using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder?

Comment: thanks for your help!!!
I realized its sort method.

And I want to achieve one more thing.
Can you help me plz

Comment: If you have a new problem please start a new question. If you solved this one,  please add an Answer below so we can all see it. See also [ask] and [answer]. Don't change your existing question into a different one - that's not how Stackoverflow works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this Question is solved by this method

```
       var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

            eventOrder:['resourceId'],
```

(documets to solve its Question is there.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder)